# Calling a Class function in the constructor/function of an other class

Tags: c++, class, object

I am getting an error while trying to call

> deck.drawCard()

inside the

> player.addCard()

or inside the constructor of the player. Note that **Class Deck** and **Class Player** are in separate files and objects **deck** and **player** are created in the main.cpp file. I linked the headers just fine in my opinion so I do not see the problem.

The error I am getting is **"deck" was not declared in this scope**

Comment: [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared in one function are not accessible in another.  You will need to pass the `deck` variable to the `Player::addCard` function, perhaps like so:

```
class Player {
public:
    void addCard(Deck& deck);
    // ...
};

void Player::addCard(Deck& deck) {
    deck.drawCard();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It works fine when I just give deck variable but when I pass the &deck it pops up an error "no matching functions for call to 'Player::Player(Deck*), Player player(&deck)'"